# What is the mechanism for the reaction of (Ph)2CO and succinic acid with NaH and quenching with acid?

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism

[image]

I'm guessing the C=O will be attacked first on the PhCOPh, but how do you get rid of the O?

Just out of interest, how else could you convert C=O to C=C?

Comment: I presume this is multiple equivalents of NaH. How strong a base do you think NaH is?

Comment: Reminiscent of the Stobbe Condensation with succinate esters. The reaction is conceivable but questionable as described. Do you have a legitimate reference for this reaction?

Comment: Interesting. The Stobbe condensation apparently goes via a cyclic intermediate that ultimately results in the 'hydrolysis' of one of the two esters https://pubs.acs.org/doi/10.1021/ja01157a133 , https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Condensation_de_Stobbe . NaH has also been used apparently https://pubs.acs.org/doi/pdf/10.1021/ja01157a130 . But yeah, starting from the dicarboxylic acid... hmm...

Comment: Thank you, Stobbe condensation does seem to provide a viable mechanism. The source is a past-paper question from a first-year undergrad chemistry exam.

Comment: Starting from the anion of succinate dicarboxylate, the first step in the reaction will be similar to the Stobbe condensation BUT it is highly unlikely that the resultant alkoxide will add to a resonance stabilized carboxylate to form a lactone. I suspect that this question is made up.

Comment: Welcome to Chemistry! On Chemistry mathematical and chemical expressions can be formatted using MathJax (and LaTeX Syntax).  If you want to know more, please have a look [here](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/86/4945) and [here](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/443/4945). We prefer to not use MathJax in the title field, see [here](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/149/4945) for details. cc @user55119